# Running Aspnet 5 on Linux based Apache server

Tags: apache, mono, asp.net-core

Is Apache on Linux server ready to host Aspnet 5 web applications? So far I have tried nginx servers on linux for running these applications. But since Apache is the leader web server, willing to use it, if possible.

Comment: You can use `Apache` as a reverse proxy and self host your app as you do with `nginx`

Comment: Thanks agua from mars